# Onde deve ser realizado a manipulação de exceções para exibir ao usuário do sistema?

Tags: java, mvc, exceção, view, controller

Qual é o melhor local para manipular uma exceção e enviar uma mensagem para o usuário do sistema em uma aplicação desktop? No controlador, na visão ou em outro local?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No controlador.

A sua camada de modelo pode produzir exceções caso seja tentado realizar alguma operação não permitida ou se a operação a ser realizada falha.

O controlador então captura este erro e decide como a camada de visão irá mostrá-lo.

A camada de visão tem como responsabilidade, mostrar o erro, e talvez capturar uma ação do usuário dizendo o que fazer. Mas não é responsabilidade dela tratar o erro.

O tratamento de erros faz parte do controle de fluxo da aplicação. E controle de fluxo é responsabilidade do controlador.

Answer (score 8):

Em primeiro lugar não abuse de captura de exceções. Tenha certeza que pode fazer algo útil quando captura uma e sempre capture a exceção mais específica possível.

Infelizmente o Java abusa das exceções para se comunicar com os diversos componentes. A linguagem usa este mecanismo para fluxo normal da aplicação.

Dito isto, entenda que pode ser necessário capturar exceções em qualquer ponto.

Durante a execução do modelo podem ocorrer exceções que precisam ser manipuladas ali mesmo.

O mesmo vale para as visões, mas deveria ser raro uma visão ter alguma exceção.

Como as visões normalmente não devem ter ações complexas e não diretamente relacionada com a apresentação, estas manipulações na maior parte das vezes invocará uma ação do controlador.

**Grande parte das exceções poderão ser interceptadas no controlador** já que será comum o modelo lançá-las. Lembrando que uma provável ação quando uma exceção é capturada aqui será a chamada de um visão para informar o usuário.

Claro que isto depende da forma e principalmente que *framework* MVC que está trabalhando. Alguns deles possuem modos próprios de manipulação geral de exceções.

Em geral o local mais adequado de captura da aplicação em si, e não o que deve ser totalmente tratado no modelo ou na visão de forma auto contida é o controlador que como o nome diz controla todo fluxo da aplicação.

Com poucos detalhes não posso ser mais específico.