# Preciso usar o try/catch em toda a cadeia de um processo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exceção, try-catch

Supondo que tenho uma chamada na minha camada *controller* para um método na camada de negócio que leva a outro método na camada de acesso aos dados.

Devo usar o `try/catch` em todas elas, só em alguma ou depende?

Abaixo, como exemplo, estou usando em todas as partes.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    try{
       var lista = ObterDadosIndicadores();
    }
    catch{
        throw;
    }
}
```

Negócio:

```
    public List<IndicadorProdutoDTO> ObterDadosIndicadores()
    {
        try
        {
            return _dal.ObterDadosIndicadores();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

DAL:

```
public List<IndicadorProdutoDTO> ObterDadosIndicadores()
    {
        try
        {
            return lstIndicador;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            FecharConexao();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Só deve usar *try/catch* se tiver condições para tratar/resolver a excepção.

Comment: @ramaral, sua colocação implica que uma aplicação poderá entrar em estado de HANG (travada) e/ou LOOP infinito e/ou CRASH, simplesmente por que não há um tratamento para a falha/erro interno.

Comment: É exatamente isto que deve ocorrer se há um erro interno. Tentar continuar uma aplicação neste estado é a última coisa que se deve fazer. Agora se quiser antes de quebrar fazer alguma coisa simples, por exemplo, tentar *logar* o erro, já é alguma coisa útil a se fazer.

Comment: @lsalamon Subscrevo o que o bigown disse.

Comment: Discordo totalmente, um programa que não tem gerenciamento correto de falhas não serve para ambiente de produção corporativo. Imagine 150 servidores executando seu código e você não faz tratamento correto de erros, deixando que seu programa caia em estado de falha. Esta não é a política correta para um desenvolvedor.

Comment: Acho que o @ramaral concorda comigo e com você que o gerenciamento correto de falhas é fundamental. Talvez nossa discordância é com sua posição de fazer de conta de que nada ocorreu e tentar continuar em um estado inadequado. Este não é o gerenciamento correto. Boa sorte em ter 150 servidores rodando um código errado capturando exceções sem ter condições de fazer alguma coisa útil com ela. Pode levar anos pra perceber que tem algo errado. Mas pode dar sorte e o .Net não deixar ir pra frente por conta dele.

Comment: @lsalamon Mais uma vez concordo com o que o bigown disse. Gerir pode não ser equivalente a tratar/resolver, por exemplo ignorar a excepção é uma forma de geri-la, mas é errada. Na grande maioria dos casos as excepções devem-se deixar propagar até ao nível superior da aplicação e só aí serem tratadas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depende da necessidade. Essa é uma das coisas que não dá para responder sem ver o código real, a situação específica. Não existe fórmula mágica, "boa prática", ou coisa do tipo. Tem que ter profundo entendimento do funcionamento das exceções para usá-la corretamente em todas as situações, de um jeito diferente de acordo com cada necessidade. Precisa ter um motivo pra por um `try-catch`. Se tiver, pode colocar em todos os lugares. Se for pra capturar e jogar pra frente, não é motivo, a não ser que realmente tenha algo útil que deve ser feito parcialmente naquele ponto.

Nos três exemplos mostrados, não deve usar a captura da exceção já que não está fazendo nada com ela. Relançá-la, ainda mais nos dois últimos exemplos é algo desnecessário, e até ruim. Se não fará algo útil com a exceção não a capture.

Mas se tiver que capturar e fazer algo útil, que seja a exceção mais específica possível. A captura de `Exception` só deve ocorrer quando tudo falhou. Só dá para fazer algo útil quando se sabe exatamente qual foi a exceção. `Exception` é genérica demais para isto. A captura desta exceção tão genérica normalmente só serve para *logar* o problema e possivelmente abandonar a execução da aplicação de forma mais agradável ao usuário.

Mas note que *logar* o erro é algo que: ou tem que ser uma forma muito específica e aí cabe a captura, ou deve deixar para um lugar centralizado *logar* de forma genérica. Não se deve ficar repetindo código por toda a aplicação.

O caso do DAL é bem esquisito. Ele tenta fechar uma conexão que ele não abriu? Isso não é correto. Quem abriu deve fechar a conexão. Aí se fizer assim, basta usar o `using` para garantir o fechamento.

Deve ter visto um monte de código assim. Tudo errado! Funciona? Em muitos casos funciona, mas funcionar e estar certo são coisas bem diferentes. O que é errado, uma hora deixa de funcionar.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Só para dar um parâmetro, eu tenho aplicações com apenas um `try-catch`. Mesmo aplicações grandes e complexas não costumam passar muito de "meia dúzia" destas estruturas de controle em todo o código (claro que uso alguns truques). A maioria dos programadores abusam de um recurso que desconhecem sua real finalidade. Em geral a pessoa acha que colocando uma captura faz o código dar menos erros, quando na verdade apenas escondem erros.

Tem linguagens que exigem um pouco mais o uso de [exceções porque usam esse mecanismo como controle de fluxo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101), o que é um abuso do mecanismo. Por sorte o C# não faz assim e não incentivam esse uso. Infelizmente materiais de péssima qualidade ensinam abusar.

Tenho [uma resposta que fala bastante sobre exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101).

Outras perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Há algum inconveniente em sempre capturar Exception e não algo mais específico?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101)
- [Como melhor tratar exceções em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101)
- [É uma boa prática lançar exceção nesses casos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre "throw" e "throw ex"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34181/101)
- [Usar um catch vazio é uma prática ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107887/101)
- [Que tipo de tratamento pode ser realizado nesse caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44501/101)
- [Onde deve ser realizado a manipulação de exceções para exibir ao usuário do sistema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103296/101)

Algumas são de linguagens diferentes, mas a informação vale.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bigown, obrigado pelas explicações e desculpe pelo código que foi totalmente fake, pois achei que não seria necessário. O que eu quis mostrar com aqueles três métodos é que um chama o outro e que o último método já possui try/catch, logo eu não sabia se era necessário os métodos anteriores terem.

Comment: De qualquer forma já foi esclarecedor o suficiente!